# Need to understand use of chrome.InitializeContentImpl

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, uipath

I found below code in an extension and I am unable to understand the use of chrome.InitializeContentImpl.

```
function InitializeContent(message)
{
    if (chrome.InitializeContentImpl) 
            {
                // hook for implementation dependent initialization
                chrome.InitializeContentImpl(message.tab);
                chrome.InitializeContentImpl = null;
            } 
}
```

Can anyone tell which function is it? because I am unable to find it on google.

Comment: It doesn't seem to an official API. Maybe it is created somewhere else in the extension's code?

Comment: It is a part of UI Path extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/uipath-web-automation/dkgencfabioofgdmhhjljpkbbchbikbh

Comment: It's just something the extension adds itself, [there's no such API](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=InitializeContentImpl).

Comment: But how and from where?

Comment: Duh. Inspect or debug the extension's code.

Comment: I guess I tried debugging, that's how I got this code. Can you try debugging and understand. extension link - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/uipath-web-automation/dkgencfabioofgdmhhjljpkbbchbikbh

Comment: Inspecting the source code shows `eval()` is used in the content script so it must be where InitializeContentImpl is added. There are no other explanations. The message is sent from the background script and its contents is transferred from a separate native messaging host. Basically this entire extension is a backdoor to execute external scripts.

Comment: So, how can we load external scripts from native host?, and I guess that script is not visible to the user. even if the user customizes the code, and apply console.log() or any other way.